# how to get code from json object

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am working with volley for network calling in android. my webservice is send me response object like that

```html
{
   "Code": 200,
   "Message": "Record Found",
   "Result": {
      "deviceid": 10,
      "udid": "359447060356151",
      "businessid": 1,
      "usertype": "Merchant"
   }
}
```

now i want to read the code and message from this object. but failed to do so. I am using this code for getting this data.

```html
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject userDetails = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Result");
LoginResponse entryObj = new LoginResponse();
entryObj.businessid = userDetails.getInt("businessid");
lr.businessid = entryObj.businessid;
Utilities.businessId = lr.businessid;
```

help me to read the code from this object. i am not getting the exact solution.

Comment: did you debugged that are you getting value or not?

Comment: check below answer .

Comment: I have  upvoted answer, that is right you code is int so you have to use getInt()

Comment: @Mohit upvote my answer too. My question is the reason of this answer.I don't know why people downvote the question without giving reason. by the way first answer is the correct in my issue. thanks to all

Comment: what do mean by *my answer too* ?

Comment: @Mohit  Oh sorry 
My question

Answer (score 3):

```
int code = jsonObj.getInt("Code");
String message = jsonObj.getString("Message");
```

This is how you read code and message.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can get code string from json using parsing,

```
JsonObject jsonObj=new jsonObject(response);
String code=jsonObj.optString("Code");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
int code = jsonObj.getInt("Code");
String message = jsonObj.getString("Message");
```